# Find img tag on page, create og:image meta tag and append to head

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api

My plan is to find the first img on a page and automatically create the og:image tag in the head. However, for some reason, although the following code finds the first meta tag, when I try to append something to it, or add something before it, it doens't work. Any help and whether this is worthwhile or not, appreciated.

This is my code so far

```
function img_find() {
    var imgs = document.getElementsByTagName("img");
    var imgSrcs = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < imgs.length; i++) {
        imgSrcs.push(imgs[i].src);
    }
    return imgSrcs;
}
var img = img_find();
var ogmetatag = document.createElement('meta');
ogmetatag.content = img[0];

var metatags = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')[0];
console.log(metatags);
metatags.appendChild(ogmetatag);
//    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
//     var img = jQuery('img').attr('src');
//     jQuery("meta[property='og:image']").attr('content', img);
//     jQuery('head').append('hiya');
// });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are missing here is adding the metatag to the page (i.e. header), you only created it in the DOM. You could do something like this:

```
var img = img_find();
var ogmetatag = document.createElement('meta');
ogmetatag.setAttribute('property', 'og:image');
ogmetatag.setAttribute('content', img[0]);
document.head.appendChild(ogmetatag);
```

Not sure if metatags that are generated with JavaScript would be accessible to the robots though.

Answer (score 1):

replace this line:

```
metatags.appendChild(ogmetatag);
```

with this:

```
metatags.parentNode.insertBefore(ogmetatag, metatags.nextSibling);
```